# FFMpeg: Buffer overflow while Slideshow => Variable FPS => Constant FPS

Tags: ffmpeg, video-conversion, framerate

I have a ~1h slideshow in the concat demuxer format (`-f concat -i input.txt`). There are at most 20 slides. I'd like to produce a constant-framerate H264 MP4.

I do:

```
 ffmpeg -f concat -i vcd.txt -preset ultrafast -crf 50 -profile:v main -tune stillimage -s:v 1920x1080 -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -framerate 5 -filter:v fps=5 outputtest.mp4
```

However this freezes because it uses up all my RAM. Just before I abort it, its RAM usage increases by 800 MB/s.

I tried saving the Variable FrameRate MP4 and then convert it to CFR:

- `ffmpeg -i outputvfr.mp4 -r 5 outputvf2fixed.mp4`
- `ffmpeg -i outputvfr.mp4 -filter:v fps=5 outputvf2fixed.mp4`
- `ffmpeg -i outputvfr.mp4 -vf settb=AVTB,fps=5 outputvf2fixed.mp4`
- `ffmpeg -i outputvfr.mp4 -vsync cfr -framerate 5 outputvf2fixed.mp4`

All of these return `Too many packets buffered for output stream 0:1.`

Otherwise:

- I don't want to manually duplicate images and provide them to FFMpeg.
- I don't want to run FFMpeg multiple times with small fragments then use concat again (this doesn't seem to be the correct way to use FFMpeg)

What is the correct way to control buffer supply?

Comment: What are the concat inputs? Is there an audio stream?

Comment: @Gyan PNG slideshow

Comment: The error msg indicates there's a 2nd stream. Share full log of concat cmd.

Comment: @Gyan I removed the audio stream completely now and `Variable FPS => Constant FPS` now completes with acceptable RAM use. Still, `Slideshow => Constant FPS` direct kills my computer, but I can live with this workaround. So there's no way to limit buffer speed?